# Booting from USB inside VMware Workstation

Tags: usb, vmware, virtualization

I'm attempting to install Windows 7 inside a VMware Workstation virtual machine using a bootable USB stick, however the VMware BIOS does not detect the stick, and so I cannot boot from it. The stick works perfectly for installing Windows directly onto the HDD (which I've already done) so there's no problem there, and the stick is being recognise by VMware as I have the option to disconnect it.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  I have a Lubuntu USB stick for recovery purposes, but I does not work on my PC, while it does in EVERYTHING else.  I tried using it on virtualbox, but it does not appear in the boot menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vmware BIOS doesn't support that feature but you can do a bridge to support this feature, the explanation [here](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000250.htm)

Comment: This sounds good.  I will try it on VirtualBox.

Comment: well, first attempt failed.  The VM froze when I chose USB from the PLoP menu.  I used VirtualBox.  Maybe VMware is needed.